# Delete from a table using two columns and multiple other tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Using SQL Server 2008, I'm trying to come up with a succinct way of deleting records from a table only if ID's from two of its columns are not in **all** three other tables. Using these tables as an example:

`table1`

```
ID1  ID2
--------
 A    1
 B    1
```

`table2`

```
ID1  ID2
--------
 A    1
 B    1
```

`table3`

```
ID1  ID2
--------
 A    1
 B    1
```

`table4`

```
ID1  ID2
--------
 A    1
```

I would like to delete records from `table1` where ID1 and ID2 do not both exist in tables 2-4. After deleting based on these conditions, `table1` should simply be left with:

```
ID1    ID2
----------
 A      1
```

Comment: Are you sure about what table1 should be left with?  `A 1` is in tables 2-4.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

Use `NOT exists` and `Inner join` could make your expect.

```
DELETE table1
WHERE NOT exists 
(
    SELECT 1
    FROM table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN table2 t2 on t1.ID1 = t2.ID1 and t1.ID2 = t2.ID2
    INNER JOIN table3 t3 on t1.ID1 = t3.ID1 and t1.ID2 = t3.ID2
    INNER JOIN table4 t4 on t1.ID1 = t4.ID1 and t1.ID2 = t4.ID2
    WHERE table1.ID1 = T1.ID1 AND table1.ID2 = T1.ID2
)
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/a810a/1

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

```
delete from table1
where id1 + castid2 as varchar(10)
in 
(select id1 + castid2 as varchar(10)
from table1
except 
select id1 + castid2 as varchar(10)
from table2
)
and 
id1 + castid2 as varchar(10)
in 
(same for the other tables).
```